# My Spring cloud gateway gets ResourceAccessException for Keycloak while using docker-compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a sample project which consists of a registry module that starts a Eureka server, a spring cloud gateway, and Keycloak.
The problem is by running Keycloak, registry using docker-compose and the gateway as a normal application, everything works, that is, when I want to see the eureka dashboard, I get redirected to Keycloak to authenticate and then redirected to the dashboard, but it is not the case when I execute the gateway together with others using docker-compose and it complains:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://127.0.0.1:8090/auth/realms/dev"
```

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://127.0.0.1:8090/auth/realms/dev/.well-known/openid-configuration": Connection refused
```

while I can get the configuration by pasting the link in the browser.
I expect it to be my misconfiguration with docker-compose and I would appreciate it if you can give me some ideas.

**gateway application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: firstService
          uri: lb://first-microservice
          predicates:
            - Path=/first/**
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
            - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
        - id: secondService
          uri: lb://second-microservice
          predicates:
            - Path=/second/**
          #          filters:
          #            - StripPrefix=1
          filters:
            - TokenRelay=
            - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
        - id: registry
          uri: lb://registry
          predicates:
            - Path=/registry/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
        - id: eureka
          uri: lb://registry
          predicates:
            - Path=/eureka/**
  autoconfigure:
    # TODO: remove when fixed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6314
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: backend
            client-secret: '2baa28ce-9607-44a3-a42c-a0bb2102a66d'
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${ISSUER_URI:http://127.0.0.1:8090/auth/realms/dev}
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username

server:
  port: 8079

info:
  app:
    name: ${spring.application.name}

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local  # is already local by default
  keycloak-data-volume:
    driver: local  # is already local by default
#    external: true


services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - net
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:11.0.0
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: Pa55w0rd
    volumes:
      - keycloak-data-volume:/var/lib/keycloak/data
    command: ["-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10"]
    expose:
      - 8090
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - net
  registry:
    image: sample-cloud-registry:latest
    container_name: registry
    expose:
      - 8761
    networks:
      - net
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER=http://registry:8761/eureka/
  gateway:
    image: sample-cloud-gateway:latest
    container_name: gateway
    expose:
      - 8079
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:8079
    networks:
      - net
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - registry
      - keycloak
    environment:
      - ISSUER_URI=http://127.0.0.1:8090/auth/realms/dev
      - EUREKA_SERVER=http://registry:8761/eureka/
networks:
  net:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue and here are my changes:

As I am using Eureka, I changed ISSUER_URI=http://127.0.0.1:8090/auth/realms/dev to use the hostname of keycloak container so the result is :

```
- ISSUER_URI=http://keycloak:8090/auth/realms/dev
```

You need to pay attention that the port number in the above line is the container port and not necessarily the host port.
And then, you need to add keycloak to your known hosts under etc to let login page be accessible via browser:

```
127.0.0.1 keycloak
```